# SA_Base.framework update

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, ipad

We have a iPad app which has Salesforce integrated in it. Initially Salesforce team had developed this app and they have used a framework called SA_Base.framework. Now, I am trying to update the salesforce sdk with latest version. But, I can't find the updated version of SA_Base.framework. Do we have an updated version of this framework or should we rewrite the whole framework?

Comment: The only Google results for `SA_Base.framework` are this question and other places you've asked something similar. Perhaps this is not a Salesforce framework and instead something custom in your app?

Comment: Alternatively, the version of the Salesforce SDK in your app might be [at least 2.5 years old](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/530).

Comment: Yes, it is very old version and SA_Base is SF internal framework I believe. It has all custom alertviews, popovers and nsconnection performing REST operations etc., Is there any alternative library which does this?

Comment: You can use a modern version of the mobile SDK for REST or [superfell's zksforce](https://github.com/superfell/zksforce) for SOAP. I would not consider it safe to use internal frameworks, especially very old ones.